# Como puedo optimizar una mascara en pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Estuve investigando y supe que las mascaras gastan muchos recursos y quería conocer un poco sobre como puedo llegar a utilizarlas correctamente o si es mejor el usar otro tipo de colisiones

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.